# Creating .jar with gradle causes a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, gson

I use vscode and gradle to build my java jar. In the project I import com.google.gson.Gson and can create an object of Gson. If I run the code everything works fine, but if I use gradlew build to create the jar and when I try to executed the jar file then I get this Error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/GsonBuilder"

> ```
> dependencies {
>     // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
>     testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
>
>     // This dependency is used by the application.
>     implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
>     implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'
> } 
> jar {
> manifest {
>     attributes(
>             'Main-Class': 'analyser.Run'
>     )
> } }
> ```

I do not understand what is wrong here. Any  ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a mistake in the build.gradle, now it works by using

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'distribution'
}
```